# remove node from `SimpleXMLElement Object`

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

`XMl` like below,

```
<text font-family="Helvetica" font-size="25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
    <tspan x="-100" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
    <tspan x="-93" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">e</tspan>
    <tspan x="-79" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">s</tspan>
    <tspan x="-66" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
</text>
```

What i want to do is, keep first `tspan` and append all other `tspan` value on first `tspan` and remove all other.

He is the desired output,

```
<text font-family="Helvetica" font-size="25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
    <tspan x="-100" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">test</tspan>
</text>
```

For this what i did,

```
$previousValue = null;
$first = $text->tspan[0];
foreach($text->tspan as $k2=>$span){
                if(is_object($span)){
                    $style = $span->attributes()->style;
                    if($previousValue) {
                        if(strcmp($style,$previousValue) === 0){
                            $first.=$span;
                            //$dom=dom_import_simplexml($span); $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
                        }
                    }
                    $previousValue = $style;
                }
            }
            $text->tspan[0] = $first;
```

That will generate first node perfect, but not removing other nodes proper.
I tried this even,

```
$dom=dom_import_simplexml($span); $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
```

But it just removing 1 node and break the loop then. Dont know what happening there. Am i doing any mistake there?

Answer (score 1):

Using [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) you can do this like following:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$texts = $xml->xpath('//text/tspan/..');

foreach ($texts as $text) {
    $tspans = $text->xpath('//tspan');;

    $currentTspan = array_shift($tspans);


    foreach ($tspans as $tspan) {
        if ($currentTspan['style']->asXML() != $tspan['style']->asXML()) {
            $currentTspan = $tspan;
            continue;
        }

        $currentTspan[0] .= $tspan[0];

        unset($tspan[0]);
    }
}
```

[Here is working demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f977da0e0d3ca2c2f65c9c5a4ac917eb5559623d)

I have used [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) function here for the simplicity. All it does is returning the first element of an array and removes it.

Comment: i am using this cide in foreach of `xmlobject` and seems like `tspans = $xml->xpath('//tspan');` not working there. I have just added part of xml  here. you can see my complete xml here. https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/images/export_edited.svg

Comment: and here is my complete code sample http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e80bf5d738cc65b6c145cb047b6f195a67364fe

Comment: thanks for the reply, but still its not working according to my xml. have you  seen it? it has `g` tag as well. i know we are quit near and small thing will make it working. but i am complete new on xmlobject

Comment: here is the latest code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e94e2507acd268dafde54c891037190c74d1564d